# How can I scan for bluetooth devices in a WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth

I need to get a list of bluetooth devices in pairing mode. UWP documentation shows a clear way of doing this; but, not for WPF. I am using this in a WPF async method-

```
var devices = await 
              DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(                
                                             RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                                                  RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(device);
        }
```

I am getting does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' exception.

How can I get all bluetooth devices in pairing mode, preferably gamepads or controllers?

Comment: There are 3 ways: WinRT (UWP) API (use DeviceWatcher), Native Win32 API or one of third party libraries: 32feet or Bluetooth Framework.

Comment: I have tried using the 32feet library but it does not return a list of bluetooth devices.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not 32feet developer but as far as I know it uses the same WinRT (UWP) API. So you can use DeviceWatcher directly. Or try Bluetooth Framework.

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: Yes, https://www.btframework.com

Comment: How do I use device watcher?

Comment: How do I use DevicePicker in winform or wpf?

Comment: Here si good stating point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client

Answer (score 0):

[`DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync) does not return a task, and can't be awaited.

However you can call `.AsTask()` and `await` that.

```
var asyncOp = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

var devices = await asyncOp.AsTask();
```

Note : I haven't tested this.

Comment: I am getting an exception- does not contain definition for 'AsTask'. I used the code in  an async method.